# how to make an if in a AWK stament

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, awk, sum

I have two files with a count for date, I'm trying to add in bash the count of both files if the date is the same, something like the following. I don't know how to use **if** with **awk**.

If I only do this I can get the total by replacing the total in the field $1

```
while read s; do while read p; do echo $s" "$p | awk '$1=$1+$3 {print $1" "$2}' ; done < FILE1 ;
done < FILE2
```

but I want to validate if the date is the same for each line:

```
while read s; do while read p; do echo $s" "$p | awk '{if ($2 == $4) $1=$1+$3 print $1" "$2 else print $1" "$2}' ; done < FILE1 ;
done < FILE2

FILE1
100 11/11/2019
200 12/11/2019
300 11/11/2019

FILE2
150 11/11/2019
260 12/11/2019
300 13/11/2019
```

For Example

I'm reading both files and showing them with the while something like:

When I do

```
echo $s" "$p
```

I get:

```
100 11/11/2019 150 11/11/2019
```

so I use `awk` to add fields 1 and 3 that is a count per date and I get the total if I use `echo $s" "$p | awk '$1=$1+$3 {print $1" "$2}'`

```
250 11/11/2019
```

What I want to do is validate that the dates in fields 2 and 4 are the same - if so, add them. If not, just print fields 1 and 2

```
200 12/11/2019 300 13/11/2019
```

Sum if 2 = 4 else print 1 and 2

```
200 12/11/2019
```

I don't know if this makes sense.

I hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: From your description it's not clear to me what the desired output is ... can you please add that?

Comment: sure for example I'm reading both files and showing them with the while something like:

When I do the echo echo $s" "$p I got:
100 11/11/2019 150 11/11/2019

so I use awk to sum the fiel 1 and 3 that is a count per date and I got the sum if I use echo $s" "$p | awk '$1=$1+$3 {print $1" "$2}'

250 11/11/2019

and what I want to do is to validate if the dates in filed 2 and 4 are the same if so sum them if not just print field 1 and 2
200 12/11/2019 300 13/11/2019
Sum if 2 = 4 else print 1and 2
200 12/11/2019 

I don't know if I made a sense

Comment: @JonathanViana please post additional information to question, hard to understand the comment. Can you clarify the following: (1) are the input file sorted (2) can there be duplicates in the input (there are two records for 11/11/2019) (3) what should be done for records without matches

Answer (score 4):

You need to put `;` between statements, and if you have multiple statements in an `if` or `else` block you need to wrap them in curly braces.

```
awk '{if ($2 == $4) {$1=$1+$3; print $1" "$2} else print $1" "$2}'
```

Since you're printing the same thing in both cases, you can do the summing in a separate action.

```
awk '$2 == $4 { $1 = $1 + $3 } {print $1" "$2}'
```

Comment: I'd like to expand on this: the `if` statement can be implicit, as you see in the second example `$2 == $4 { $1 = $1 + $3 }`, which is equivalent to `if ($2 == $4) { $1= $1 + $3 }`. You might also want to give the `OFS` a go. By default, it is a single whitespace, so this code should also be fine: `{print $1,$2}`.

Answer (score 0):

I do it more easier using pr

```
pr -m -t FILE1 FILE1

100 11/11/2019  100  11/11/2019 
200 12/11/2019  200  12/11/201 
300 13/11/2019  300  14/11/2019
```

So I want to sum fields 1 and 3 if the date is the same in each line:

```
pr -m -t FILE1 FILE2 | awk  '{if ($2 == $4) {print $1=$1+$3" "$2} else {print $1" "$2}}'

200 11/11/2019
400 12/11/2019
300 13/11/2019
```

sorry for made my question so confuse. also I was using in wrong way the if statement into the awk